# ApprovalTests.Asp.Mvc has an error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller, approval-tests

I'm using ApprovalTests, and

```
using ApprovalTests.Asp;
```

doesn't have errors. On the other hand, I get an error when i try to use ApprovalTests.Asp.Mvc:

```
using ApprovalTests.Asp.Mvc;
```

Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'ApprovalTests.Asp' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

how can i fix it?

Comment: I executed `Install-Package ApprovalTests.Asp` on Package Manager Console and I can use `ApprovalTests.Asp.Mvc` in code. Check if you have required dependencies and the package included in `References` list in unit test project.

Comment: I've tried installing mvc 3 and it didn't worked, I thought it did but in the end i've got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed  ApprovalTests version to 1.9,
Appearntly I wasn't working on the same version that was at the tutorial.